# Determine if an MQ queue is an error queue or not

Tags: ibm-mq

In MQ explorer, If I open up the properties for a particular queue (X), what property will tell me if the queue is defined as an error handling queue for another queue (Y)? i.e. If Y fails to process the message and the transaction rolls back, it will put the message on X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any queue designated as an error or exception queue (backout queue in WebSphere MQ terminology) is an ordinary queue.  The `BOQNAME` on a primary queue points to the backout queue but there is no attribute of the backout queue that points back to the primary queue.  This might be a one-to-many relationship because any number of primary queues might point to a single backout queue.

One way to do this in WMQ Explorer would be to make sure that `BOQNAME` is visible in the display and then sort the queue list on that column.  Then look for all instances with your backout queue name in them.